# My virtual destructor will not be called in a abstract class

Tags: c++

My program will not call the base class's virtual destructor. I found this method on 
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/virtual-destructors/
So I don't know what is wrong. Can please someone help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Number{
    private:
        int *arr;
        int n;
    public:
        Number(int *a, int i):
            arr(a),n(i){}
        virtual vector<int> operator()()=0;
        int* getArr(){return arr;}
        int getValueAt(int i){return arr[i];}
        int size(){return n;}
        virtual ~Number(){ delete [] arr;
            cout<<"In Number destructor"<<endl;
        }
};

class Odd: public Number{
    public:
        Odd(int *ar,int n1):
            Number(ar,n1){}
        vector<int> operator()();
        ~Odd(){}
};

class Even: public Number{
    public:
        Even(int *ar,int n1):
            Number(ar,n1){}
        vector<int> operator()();
        ~Even(){}
};

/*
 *      operator()()
 *  -input
 *      none
 *  -description
 *      returns a vector with all the
 *      odd numbers. This will be sent in
 *      as a function parameter to a
 *      higher order function
 *  -output
 *      vector<int> with odd values
 */
vector<int> Odd::operator ()()
{
    vector<int> temp;
    for(int i=0; i<Number::size(); i++){
        if(Number::getArr()[i]%2==1)
            temp.push_back(Number::getValueAt(i));
    }
    return temp;
}

/*
 *      operator()()
 *  -input
 *      none
 *  -description
 *      returns a vector with all the
 *      even numbers. This will be sent in
 *      as a function parameter to a
 *      higher order function
 *  -output
 *      vector<int> with even values
 */
vector<int> Even::operator ()()
{
    vector<int> temp;
    for(int i=0; i<Number::size(); i++){
        if(Number::getArr()[i]%2==0)
            temp.push_back(Number::getValueAt(i));
    }
    return temp;
}

/*
 *      filter()
 *  input:
 *      Takes a number object
 *  description:
 *      filter is a higher order function and
 *      it will return a vector with depending
 *      how the operator() is defined
 *  output:
 *      vector<int>
 */
vector<int> filter(Number *a)
{
    return (*a)();
}

/*
 *      addAll()
 *  input:
 *      Takes a number object
 *  description:
 *      addAll is a higher order function and
 *      it will return sum of a vector returned
 *      from a filtering process that depends on
 *      the definition of operator() being invoked
 *  output:
 *      vector<int>
 */
int addAll(Number *a)
{
    vector<int> temp=(*a)();
    int sum=0;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i< temp.size();i++){
        sum+=temp[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

/*
 *  This program was written to explore functional programming
 *  concepts in c++. One such concept is high order functions
 *
 *  I created an abstract Number class which contains an int
 *  array and size of the array. I also made two derived classes
 *  that define the virtual operator() function. I pass a 
 *  polymorphic pointer variable to the higher order functions
 *  and they call the overloaded operator()() which is dynamically
 *  binded during runtime and the correct vector and sum should be 
 *  returned by the functions
 *  
 *  One bug that I have is that the base destructor is not being called
 *  warning!! this function will cause memory leaks
 */
int main()
{
    int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Number *even=new Even(array,sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
    Number *odd=new Odd(array,sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));

    vector<int> temp=filter(even);
    cout<<"The even numbers in array are: ";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<temp.size();i++){
        cout<<temp[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"The sum of all the even numbers is "
        <<addAll(even)<<endl;

    temp=filter(odd);
    cout<<"The odd numbers in array are: ";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<temp.size();i++){
        cout<<temp[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"The sum of all the odd numbers is "
        <<addAll(odd)<<endl;

    delete even;
    delete odd;
}
```

Comment: Does [**this**](http://ideone.com/9jg6DB) give you some more understandable information than you already have?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but this is very wrong:

```
Number(int *a, int i):
    arr(a),n(i){}

virtual ~Number(){ delete [] arr;
    cout<<"In Number destructor"<<endl;
}
```

You are not setting `arr` to point to dynamically allocated memory, so don't expect `delete[] arr` to work correctly when called from the destructor. In fact, it will most likely invoke a memory access violation which will abruptly terminate the program (second thought, maybe it is a direct answer to your question after all).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual destructor is a red herring, and in fact the base class destructor *is* being called, which is why you are seeing an error. Note that the point of virtual destructors is to make sure a *derived* class destructor will be called when you delete a derived object through a base class pointer.

What's happening is that you are passing `array`, a pointer to an array on the stack, to the `Number` constructor, which stores it and then happily attempts to delete it (twice, even!) when its destructor is called. A stack array does not need to, and should never, be `delete`d, let alone twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your base class destructor does get called. But it core dumps at:

`delete [] arr;`

and that's because you are trying to delete the `array` memory which is allocated on stack and not on heap.

Your program has many other issue though.

Comment: What other issues are their?